# mongoid index on polymorphic collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

Trying to work out the best way to add an index on a polymorphic association in mongoid

I have

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

class Student < User
  include Mongoid::Document

class Parent < User
  include Mongoid::Document
```

when mongoid creates data it creates a _type field

```
Parent
{
"_id" : ObjectId("51f06367b5b60561d0000003"),
"_type" : "Parent"
}
```

I want to search on type. e.g. Student.all  and noticed with the explain() there is no implict index created by mongoid.

To solve this I added an index in the User class

```
index({ _type: 1 })
```

Wondering is there a way to get mongoid to create index's automatically?
Or is there a better way to do this apart from adding the index on the User model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have here is a **subclass**, not polymorphism as mentioned in the Mongoid documentation. But, there is no automated way. Adding the index manually is the recommended approach, so you're all set!

http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/v3/documents.html#inheritance